# When changing font size, is there an unit that changes proportional to all elements (h1 h2 h3 p)?

Tags: html, css, font-size

Is there a way to change the ratio on proportional way for the different elements or do i have to setup individually for all different elements?

i tried

HTML {
font-size:150%
}

But it will put ALL text elements (h1 h2 p etc.) in same font size.
I want this to change proportional !!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use em for relatively applying font-size on them.
For example:

```css
body {
    font-size:24px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:0.5em; // for 12px or relative to the body font 
}
```

Comment: Just a note: em is a relative font size, meaning it relates to whatever it inherits from its parent style.  If you want to reference the root font size (defined in body in this answer), use rem (root em).